# Text transfer From/To SDR

Tags: gnuradio

I bought a hackrf one and I don't think it works.

Before I return it can someone show me a grc flowchart on how to send text or a text file from a hackrf to a rtlsdr?

I have been told you can do it. I have tried all of the flowcharts online and on youtube. Packet Decoder/Encoder no longer works. I have been trying to get this working for weeks and I'm about to send the hackrf back.

right now its a $569 paper weight

Comment: Hi Sean! Don't be frustrated, as SDR involves both Software *and* Radio, and that can be a lot for a beginner to cope with. You need to settle your expectations a bit, though: The hackrf doesn't transmit digital files. It's a software defined radio that transmits a digital signal defining an analog waveform, that a receiver with an appropriate algorithm can turn back into the data that was used to calculate the digital signal, given that all conditions are met. And that's a lot!

Comment: So, as you've noticed, this isn't trivial. You first need to decide on a way of putting data (e.g. a text file, or a cat video, or an emergency broadcast, or…) onto an analog band-limited waveform. I'd frankly not start with a text file – it's a hard problem to find the start of that, and shift the whole data stream by a couple of bits, and none of it makes sense anymore – I'd start with an alternation of 0 and 1 bits and see whether I can see that in my receiver. Then, add framing (that's for knowing where your data starts and how long it is!) and channel coding (that's for correcting errors,

Comment: as, unlike the simplified case of copying a file on your computer, you physically always have a chance that bits get corrupted if you transmit something over the air). I honestly don't think that you should return your HackRF – how is it the producer's fault that you've bought a device that requires extensive SDR knowledge to do something complex as transmitting a text file? However, you can get a start, by reading the [Official GNU Radio guided Tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org) from start to finish, **especially** the intro chapter. It's not straightforward, but far from impossible!

Comment: So the question really is, do you want to build your own transceiver system, or do you want your transmission to be compliant with some specific standard? Maybe you could use or at least piggy-back on an existing transceiver software.

Comment: could use something like fldigi to do the encoding if you can get the audio path set up right.